# How do I filter Excel data when records are grouped?

Tags: excel

So we all know that we can filter data in an individual column using the filter tool in Excel.

Unfortunately, I have grouped records that would appear as so:

```
ID        Total        ItemVal
1224      1,599,879    0
1224      0            15,799
1224      0            1,113,556
1224      0            470,524
1723      4,844,453    4,844,453
2078      155,433      155,433
```

In this case what I am trying to do is show all records where the Total is greater than one million.

If the total is one million, then show all records for that particular ID.

If I filter, all I get are the rows:

```
ID        Total        ItemVal
1224      1,599,879    0
1723      4,844,453    4,844,453
```

When what I actually want is:

```
ID        Total        ItemVal
1224      1,599,879    0
1224      0            15,799
1224      0            1,113,556
1224      0            470,524
1723      4,844,453    4,844,453
```

Comment: That query will only pull the single record where total value is greater than 1 million, but will not pull the other records because their "total" value is 0.  I need these records to be pulled as well.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Total, t.ItemVal
FROM Table t
WHERE t.ID In (
   select ID 
   from table 
   where total >1000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, the easiest route will be to add a helper column, with a formula like the following, which will return True/False, and that you can filter on.

`=sumif(A:A,A2,C:C)>1E6`